# Orientation-preserving/reversing parameterizations + order of cross product

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Given a surface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and its parameterization $\phi:(u \in[a,b],v \in[c,d]) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, we can have the normal vector as $\vec{n} :=\phi_u \times \phi_v$, where these represent derivative vectors of $\phi$ wrt. the indexing variable, as defining the positive orientation of $S$.

However, if we instead use $ \vec{n} := \phi_v \times \phi_u = -(\phi_u \times \phi_v)$, we get normal vector in opposite direction, i.e. giving a orientation-reversing parameterization of the surface.

That is, just by changing order of cross product, we can get orientation-reversing or preserving parameterization of the surface. But then, it doesn't make to sense talk about whether a parameterization is orientation-preserving or reversing? How do we reconcile this?

Comment: Does it help to note that the choice $\phi_u \times \phi_v$ can be unambiguously selected by convention, i.e., using the ordering $(u, v)$ of Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Right, but then I would like to know why have such a convention. Usually in mathematics, the order of variables don't matter, but here with the cross product being a non-commutative operator, we want it to matter, and so what you're saying might work. However, at the same time as mathematicians, we want to depend less on such conventions as ordering of variables. Therefore, I wonder why should a non-commutative operator arise here? Is there no commutative operator "acting on parameterizations" that can be used to define orientation?

Comment: Ordering of variables is also a "non-commutative" choice. In terms of orientation, it's precisely anti-symmetric: Permuting variables multiplies the induced orientation by the sign of the permutation. <> Generally, I'm not sure I agree that usually in mathematics the order of variables doesn't matter. In calculus and geometry we work with ordered tuples, for example, and "usually" $\phi(v, u) \neq \phi(u, v)$. (Or, perhaps that's what you're asking? If we define $\psi(u, v) = \phi(v, u)$, then aside from possibly having different domains, $\phi$ and $\psi$ "have opposite orientation.")